# Prove or disprove (local minimum of a two variable function)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be a differentiable function.

Suppose that for every line, $l$ , that passes through $(0,0)$ the point $(0,0)$ is a local minimum of $f(x,y)\mid_ l$. Does that mean that $(0,0)$ is a local minimum of $f(x,y)$?

When I first saw the question I tried to prove it by letting $l=(a,b)\cdot t$  where a,b are constants. Then I got $x=at, y=bt$ and substituted that in the function $f(x,y)$ to get $f(at,bt)$. Then I used the chain rule to differentiate $f$ , but didn't know what to do from there.

Is this a good direction? or am I suppose to disprove the claim?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can prove that the map
$$\begin{array}{l|rcl} 
f : & \mathbb{R}^2 & \longrightarrow & \mathbb{R} \\ 
    & (x,y) & \longmapsto & f(x,y)=3x^4-4x^2y+y^2 \end{array}$$

has a local minimum at zero along all lines passing through the origin.

However the origin is not a local minimum for $f$ as $f(x,2 x^2)=-x^4
$.

For more details, you can have a look at [NO MINIMUM AT THE ORIGIN BUT A MINIMUM ALONG ALL LINES](http://www.mathcounterexamples.net/no-minimum-at-the-origin-but-a-minimum-among-all-lines/).

Comment: Amazing!
Thank you :)